# Can't drop Athena table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a table in AWS Athena called: `qos-row-id`

I have tried to delete the table I have created.

```
DROP TABLE qos-row-id;
```

I recevive the following message every time I try to.

```
line 1:15: mismatched input '-' expecting {<eof>, '.'} (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: acd8a81c-8d3c-4add-9308-303980629029)
```

Comment: Please, I know it's hard, but provide a bit more of info. At least the query executed or something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another easier way to delete this table is using the AWS glue data catalog where you go and delete the table using the delete table option in the action drop down.

[image]

Important Note : Make sure that you don't create tables with an Hyphen, in your case (qos-row-id). Trying using an underscore(qos_row_id) in tablenames. This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced a similar one,considering you have delete access,

Try using the following syntax (look carefully at the back quotes `..`):

```
DROP TABLE `<DBNAME>.<qos-row-id>`;
```

Apart from this you can obviously use the GUI feature to delete.

[image]